# How do I know the expiry date of this film?

Tags: film, fujifilm, slides

I have some Fujichrome Sensia 100 here. I am quite sure this is already expired. I wanted to know for sure but could not find any date on the roll.

I guess this was some very standard slide film. I got if for free. Do such films even have an expiry date label?

At the lip the holds the opening light sealed there's a number: 1 6283230
this is **not** the number of the bar code, but it doesn't look like a date either. More like a production number.

Kind of two questions in one:
Does this film (or in general every film) have a label for the expiry date?
How do I know what the expiry date of my film was?

I know it's not a problem to use expired film, curiosity is the main motivation for my question. I shot a few rolls of this film and it always worked as expected.

Comment: From the couple of rolls I have in front of me (Kodak and Fujifilm) they do not have expiration dates on them. I do have the box for Fujifilm Superia 1600 Color Negative and with a number of `C/ 4 6256585` it expires in April 2015. I don't think we can directly reverse map unless we ask Fujufilm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All film expires. Unfortunately, film expiry dates are printed on the box (which has obviously been discarded in this case), not on the 135 film cartridge itself.

Fujifilm Sensia was discontinued in 2010. Expiry dates would be in the range of 2-3 years after manufacture.

Film should really be cold stored over longer periods, but it's entirely possible that your results with this film will turn out perfectly fine.

Comment: I read it was discontinued in 2008? I guess the exact date doesn't matter too much. Good point with the cooling, they (with the other, good films) are all on their shelf in the fridge, more or less since I got them.